# Why isn't "Return" necessary?

Tags: c, cs50

The following code is for the lab https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/labs/1/population/.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Prompt for start size
    int startPop;
    do
    {
        startPop = get_int("Starting population: ");
    }
    while (startPop < 9);
    
    //Prompt for end size
    int endPop;
    do
    {
        endPop = get_int("Ending population: ");
    }
    while (endPop < startPop);
    
    int Years = 0;
    
    while (startPop < endPop)
    {
        startPop = startPop + (startPop/3) - (startPop/4);
        Years++;
    }
   
    printf("Total Years: %i", Years);
    
}
```

Why isn't return used after each integer is received? Like this

```
  int startPop;
    do
    {
        startPop = get_int("Starting population: ");
    }
    while (startPop < 9);
    return startPop;
```

How do I know when and where to use it? What is the purpose of return?

It seems like every time I try to solve a problem I am completely off base and don't even know where/how to begin, even after hours of thinking about it and then the solution also mystifies me.

Comment: If a function does not return a value, it does not need to end with `return`. Every function that returns a value must explicitly do so, *except* `int main()` where there is an implicit `return 0` if it is missing.

Comment: Most compilers are pretty forgiving if `main` doesn't have an explicit return.  In any other function that doesn't explicitly `return` a value (save for void functions), the return value will be undefined. Most compilers will warn/error on a missing return statement from other functions.

Comment: @selbie it is not *required*.

Comment: In C, you may only return a single value (though it may be a pointer to something else) from a function. The `return` statement is followed by the value you wish to return (and it must match the type that the function is declared to return). You may return from any point within a function (so having multiple `return` statements is fine -- but only one will be used). With `void` functions a `return` **without a value** is allowed to simply return control to the calling function at the point the `return` appears.

Comment: `main` (in terms of the entrypoint method) is usually a little special in most languages that have it. Try not to base your assumptions for that method around the rest of the language.

Comment: Additionally, returning from `main()` has two general values `0` (no error) and `1` (error). C defines two macros for that purpose `EXIT_SUCCESS` (value `0`) and `EXIT_FAILURE` (value `1`). They are provided through `stdlib.h`. Beginning in C99, the `return` statement from `main()` became optional, defaulting to `0` if omitted.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The C standard does not define the value of `EXIT_FAILURE` or the meaning of returning 1 from `main`. C 2018 5.1.2.2.3 1 says returning a value from `main` is equivalent to calling `exit` with that value. 7.22.4.4 5 says `EXIT_FAILURE` returns “an implementation-defined form of the status *unsuccessful termination*” and “Otherwise [such as returning 1 when that is not `EXIT_FAILURE`] the status returned is implementation-defined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil that is a good point, but also why we used 'general' values. All major compilers, gcc, clang, VS, etc.. all define `EXIT_SUCCESS` as `0` and `EXIT_FAILURE` as `1`. I cannot think of any that do otherwise. But, that said, the standard allows compilers to make another choice,. POSIX limits the choice to zero or positive values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return will exit the function that you are currently in, and the remainder of the function will not execute. It may also return a value from that function, if it is a non-void function. Here is an example:

```
int main(void)
{
    foo()
}

void foo()
{
    //...some code...
    return;
    //..some more code...
}
```

In this case foo will be called and will run until it hits the return, at which point the execution will return to main, and all the code in foo after main will not execute.

In your program, there is only one function (main), and calling return from main will exit the program (not what we want in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The `return XX` at the end of `main` is not necessary because the C standard says so:

> C18 §5.1.2.2.3 **Program termination**
>
> ... reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of `0`.

In other words, if there is no `return xx` the `int main()` function is presumed to `return 0`.

For all other functions that return a value, the function must explicitly return a value.

For `void` functions, the `return` statement is optional.

Comment: I did not vote, but OP is not asking why `return` is not necessary at the end of `main` or to exit `main`. They seem to be asking why `return` is not necessary after certain segments of code, as if it were necessary to register the value just computed before proceeding to further code or something. In any case, they seem completely confused about what `return` does, so this answer does not speak to their question.

Comment: Downvoter here: I don't think it does, since as far as I can tell, the OP's confusion has nothing to do with the code being in `main`.

Comment: @Siguza the question title asks why `return` is not necessary and shows `int main()` without a `return` statement. That is what I answered.

Comment: The title is not the whole question. OP asks “Why isn't return used after each integer is received?” and “What is the purpose of return?” and “How do I know when and where to use it?”

Answer (score -1):

`Return` is the C syntax to tell the assembler to create a `ret` instruction.

What is a `ret` instruction? From [Intel's x86 manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html):

> **RET — Return from Procedure**
> Transfers program control to a return address located on the top of the stack. The address is usually placed on the stack by a CALL instruction, and the return is made to the instruction that follows the CALL instruction.

When you call and return from a function (here called a *procedure*), in reality you are executing the following code at assembly level:

```
push    rbp // push rbp (base pointer) to the stack
mov     rbp, rsp //  store rsp (stack pointer) into rbp.
...
mov     rsp, rbp // get back the value of rsp
pop     rbp // pop rbp from the stack
ret
```

*"The caller"* is the original function in which the call to the other function, *"the callee"* happens.

Note that by default the C language will asssume (rightfully) that every function has a return point, and that is why for void function, as well as for main, a written return is not necessary.

The return along with a value (let say 20) is translated as (intel syntax):

```
mov eax, 20
ret
```

---

*What is the relationship with your question?*

In your example, there is no call to a callee function, you are executing code inside your function (the same as what would happen if you add "inline") so the the variable you are currently calculating `startPop` doesn't need a return.

*PS: On a side note, having a do while with = does not make a lot of sense.*

Comment: The `return` that OP asks about is not the same x86's `ret` instruction; `return` is arch-agnostic C language construct and as such can be explained within the C language itself. For OP who doesn't understand `return` yet, assembly is hardly going to help and probably going to add to the confusion.